Deriving a Multivariate Normal from a Univariate Normal?
As a learning exercise, I am trying to derive a multivariate normal distribution using a univariate normal distribution.
Here is my work:
Start with $k$ independent univariate normal distributions:
$$ X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) \quad \text{for } i = 1, \ldots, k $$
Under standard circumstances (i.e. iid) joint probability density function is the product of individual PDFs:
$$ f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) = \prod_{i=1}^k f_i(x_i) $$
We know that the PDF of each univariate normal distribution is:
$$ f_i(x_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right) $$
Substituting:
$$ f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_i^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right) $$
Simplify:
$$ f(x_1, \ldots, x_k) = (2\pi)^{-k/2} \left(\prod_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2\right)^{-1/2} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\right) $$
Here is where I got a bit confused. In a multivariate normal, we usually use the following mean and variance vectors:
$$ \mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_k)^T, \quad \boldsymbol{\mu} = (\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_k)^T, \quad \boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_k^2) $$
So if we rewrite the exponent using matrix notation:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} = (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) $$
It seems we can just adjust everything else from above (keeping in mind standard exponential and square root properties) - and we get the standard multivariate normal formula as expected:
$$ f(\mathbf{x}) = (2\pi)^{-k/2} |\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|^{-1/2} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})\right) $$
Is my derivation correct? Or did I oversimplify everything too much (i.e. will this approach still work if $\Sigma$ is non-diagonal and has correlations) ?

This approach does only work if the marginal densities are independent. To see why, just consider the density of a standard normal random variable $X$ and the density of $-X$. The density of $(X,-X)$ does not exist.

To add to the comment above, if you only know the marginal distributions, the joint distribution can be arbitrary, because you can use any copula you like.

thanks everyone! could you guys please show me how to derive the multivariate normal distribution in general?
